# Executing a 'perl command' from shell and executing the same command from perl script using system command

Tags: perl, escape-characters

I am not able to take care of special characters.

I have the following perl script.

```
while(@mapping_array[$i])
{  
  chomp(@mapping_array[$i]);
  my @core= split ( /  / , $mapping_array[$i]) ;
  @core[0] =~ tr/ //ds ;   ## Deleting blank spaces
  @core[1] =~ tr/ //ds ;     
  system("perl -pi -e 's/@core[0]/@core[1]/' $testproc ");  
  print "@core[0] \n";
  print "@core[1] \n";
  $i++;
}
```

The issue is that my `@core[0]` variable could be a simple string like `abc` or a more complex one like `TEST[1]`. My script works as expected for `abc`, replacing it with the value of `@core[1]`, but it failes if my `@core[0]` is `TEST[1]`.

Using `?` instead of `/` in the substitution operator doesn't help. How can I do this correctly?

Comment: Array elements use the singular sigil: `$core[0]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for `quotemeta`. As explained in `perldoc -f quotemeta`:

```
quotemeta EXPR
        Returns the value of EXPR with all the ASCII non-"word" characters
        backslashed. (That is, all ASCII characters not matching
        "/[A-Za-z_0-9]/" will be preceded by a backslash in the returned
        string, regardless of any locale settings.) This is the internal
        function implementing the "\Q" escape in double-quoted strings.
```

So, your script would be (note that array elements should be specified as `$foo[N]`, not `@foo[N]`):

```
chomp(@mapping_array);
while($mapping_array[$i])
{  
    my @core= split ( /  / , $mapping_array[$i]) ;
    $core[0] =~ tr/ //ds ;   ## // Deleting blank spaces
    $core[1] =~ tr/ //ds ;   # / fix SO highlighting
    my($k,$l)=(quotemeta($core[0]),quotemeta($core[1]))
    system("perl -pi -e 's/$k/$l/' $testproc "); 
    print "$core[0] \n$core[1] \n";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: I was really looking for 'quotemeta'. Yes, array elements should be specified as $foo[N] and not @foo[N], I could not really figure out the difference between the two.It will be helpful if you can point out the differences.

Comment: Thanks for including the actual `quotemeta` definition from the documentation.  +1 for that.

Comment: @user3687023 `$foo[n]` is the nth element of array `@foo`, and `@foo[n]` is an [array slice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_slicing#1987:_Perl), it's a new array with one element. Try running `perl -MO=Deparse,-q -le '@F=("foo"); print "@F[0]"'`. You will see that `@F[0]` is actually `join($", @F[0])`. This sort of thing is why it's always a good idea to `use warnings;`. The code above produces this warning: `Scalar value @F[0] better written as $F[0] at -e line 1.`.

Comment: In `perl` the "sigil" (`$`, `@`, `%` etc.) denotes what data type you expect _out_ of the thing. For a single scalar therefore, it's always `$` - `$value`, `$array[$index]` or `$hash{$key}`. Perl knows what it is, because of the type of bracket you're using (if any), not by the sigil. It's perfectly valid to write `@array[1..3]` (because you're after multiple scalars). Or `@hash{("key1", "key2", "key3")}` to get a list of values matching the designated keys.

Answer (score 5):

Running Perl from Perl can usually be avoided.

```
for my $both (@mapping) {
    my ($regex, $replace) = split /  /, $both;
    tr/ //ds for $regex, $replace;                                                                   # // Fix SO highlighting bug.

    open my $IN,  '<', $testproc or die $!;
    open my $OUT, '>', "$testproc.new" or die $!;
    while (<$IN>) {
        s/\Q$regex/$replace/;
        print {$OUT} $_;
    }
    close $OUT or die $!;
    rename $testproc, "$testproc.old" or die $!;
    rename "$testproc.new", $testproc or die $!;
}
```

The \Q corresponds to [quotemeta](http://p3rl.org/quotemeta) which prevents interpretation of special characters in the $regex variable.

Answer (score 4):

First off - turn on `strict` and `warnings` at the top of your program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

This will help you identify errors like `@core[0]` isn't actually right.

However the second problem is - you're sending meta characters to your regex - `[]` means something special in regex.

So what you really need is the `quotemeta` function.

```
print quotemeta '@core[0]';
```

Which turns it into:

```
\@core\[0\]
```

Or

```
print quotemeta $core[0];
```

Which in the example you give will print:

```
TEST\[1\]
```

Of course, you also probably don't need to `system()` call `perl` from within `perl`. That's just inefficient and messy.

Answer (score 2):

Use `\Q` in the regexp to remove special meaning from chars:

```
system("perl -pi -e 's/\\Q$core[0]/$core[1]/' $testproc ");
```